# How to call a native JS function by a dynamic element inside a react class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a react app with image uploading component. That component has a file input field which allows multiple files uploading feature. I created a function to create dynamic image elements to show each uploaded image in the app component. I'm using FileReader() for this.

I create a dynamic close button for each image to remove the image. For this, I create dynamic close buttons with setting the attribute onclick = "removeImage()" as follows. **The Problem is, When I'm clicking on the Close button, The console says `"removeImage is not defined`"**

How can I solve this?

**React component**

```
//remove image element
function removeImage(domId) {
  document.getElementById(domId).remove();
}

class CreatePost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      postText: '',
    }
  }

getImage = (e) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {

      //create main div
      var mainDiv = document.createElement("div");
      mainDiv.setAttribute("class", "imgMain");
      mainDiv.setAttribute("id", `image${i}`);

      //create remove button
      var closeButoon = document.createElement("span");
      closeButoon.setAttribute("class", "closeImage");

      //set removeImage function to onclick attribute
      closeButoon.setAttribute("onClick", "removeImage(image"+i+")");
      closeButoon.innerText="X";

      mainDiv.appendChild(closeButoon);

      //add file reader part
      var file = e.target.files[i];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      if (fileType === "image") {
        let imgDiv = document.createElement("img")
        imgDiv.setAttribute("class", "imageOne")
        if (file) {
          reader.onload = function (e) {
            imgDiv.setAttribute('src', e.target.result)
          };
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
        mainDiv.appendChild(imgDiv);
        document.getElementById("imageLoader").appendChild(mainDiv)
      }
    }
  }

render() {
    return (
       <>
          <input
             type="file"
             id="inputImage"
             name="inputImage"
             accept="image/*"
             onChange={this.getImage}
             multiple
          />
          <div className="imageLoader" id="imageLoader"></div>
       </>
    )
}
};

export default CreatePost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the way you are setting the onClick handler as a string.
The function is scoped to get imaged and needs to be referenced on the spot.

`` closeButoon.onclick = () => removeImage(`image${i}`); ``

Answer (score 0):

Well this is because the function removeImage() is inside of the function that you made for your react component, and you are using the DOM directly to create your removeimage button. 
So in other words, the function removeImage() needs to be out of that class.
This is because it is trying to get the function from the global object, and now it only exist in the scope of your react component function

Comment: Creating the function out of the class resulting in the same error

Comment: you need to put "removeImage(\"image"+i+"\")" when you set the attribute onClick